# how to include 0 results in count with group by in HIVEQL

Tags: sql, database, hive, hiveql

I'm a newbie in HIVE. I want to include 0 rows in results

I have one table like

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
data_source_id,  part_hour, ...
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

this is my query

```
SELECT data_source_id, COUNT(*) as count 
FROM data_source 
WHERE part_hour = 2022041618 
GROUP BY data_source_id;
```

example result is

```
data_source_id, count
12            , 35
13            , 36
```

but my desired result is

```
data_source_id, count
12            , 35
13            , 36
15.           , 0
```

How can I get a 0 in results?

Comment: What is a "zero row" for you? Could you please add the relevant input data and the desired result? Thank you.

Comment: I edit my question more specifically thank your advice.

Comment: Thank you. But which entries are in your table "data_source"? Meaning what is the result from this query?: SELECT *
FROM data_source 
WHERE part_hour = 2022041618

Comment: That result show all of data in partition {part_hour = 2022041618}

Comment: Sorry, I was just drawing a blank. Roy's answer shoult be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this but you need to remove where clause.

```
SELECT data_source_id, 
SUM(case when part_hour = 2022041618 then 1 else 0 end ) as count 
FROM data_source  
GROUP BY data_source_id;
```

You can also do using self join.

EDIT - I changed below SQL as per your need. If you have partitions on part hour and data_source_id, your SQL should be quick.

```
select distinct d.data_source_id, nvl(rs.count,0) 
FROM 
(select distinct data_source_id from data_source) d
left join (SELECT data_source_id, COUNT(*) as count 
FROM data_source 
WHERE part_hour = 2022041618 
GROUP BY data_source_id) rs on rs.data_source_id=d.data_source_id;
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. where cluase is very important to speed of query. Can I add where cluase and GROUP BY last of query not only subquery?

Comment: The table has a lot of data. So I can't query get a all of data but only query data in specific partitions like part_hour = 2022041618.

Comment: problem is if you dont have it in the partition you need to find them in main sql. so you need a subqry to find distinct data_source_id. if you have any other table with distinct data_source_id, then you can join with that too.

Comment: I want to count in sepcific partition only. there are two partitions in hive part_hour and data_source_id

Comment: I get all data_source_id with query {select distinct data_source_id from data_source} but when I use left join query like {(select ~~~) left join (SELECT ~~~~ )}  data_source_id with zero rows doesn't exist. I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: can you pls share exact sql you r using? it may happen you do not have data source id with 9 rows.